# RijndaelManaged - What does setting KeySize property do?

Tags: c#, rijndaelmanaged

Given I am setting the KeySize to be 192, when I am encrypting some data by doing the following:

```
 static void Main()
        {
            var querystrings = "dataToEncrypt";
            byte[] keyvalue = new byte[] { 241, 205, 121, 123, 109, 246, 247, 103, 31, 225, 167, 220, 247, 119, 247, 119, 78, 125, 127, 167, 156, 213, 230, 250, };
            byte[] ivvalue = new byte[] { 194, 177, 79, 213, 87, 46, 213, 189, 243, 169, 32, 13, 217, 62, 34, 170, };
            byte[] querystringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(querystrings);

            using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 192;
                rijndaelManaged.IV = ivvalue;
                rijndaelManaged.Key = keyvalue;
                rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor();
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(querystringBytes, 0, querystringBytes.Length);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        var output = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        Console.WriteLine($"{output}");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The data encrypts as I'd expect as the IV and encryption key are 128 bits and 192 bits long respectively.  If however I set the encryption key to be 128 bits long (for arguments sake, lets use the same byte array as the IV) i.e.

```
 static void Main()
        {
            var querystrings = "dataToEncrypt";
            byte[] keyvalue = new byte[] { 194, 177, 79, 213, 87, 46, 213, 189, 243, 169, 32, 13, 217, 62, 34, 170, };
            byte[] ivvalue = new byte[] { 194, 177, 79, 213, 87, 46, 213, 189, 243, 169, 32, 13, 217, 62, 34, 170, };
            byte[] querystringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(querystrings);

            using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 192;
                rijndaelManaged.IV = ivvalue;
                rijndaelManaged.Key = keyvalue;
                rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor();
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(querystringBytes, 0, querystringBytes.Length);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        var output = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        Console.WriteLine($"{output}");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This will still encrypt without exception.  My question is:

What does the KeySize do internally as it's accepting a 128 bit encryption key when I am explicitly setting the KeySize as 192? Why is no exception occurring?

Comment: Updated my question to be more explicit about my confusion

Comment: `ICryptoTransform` inherits from `IDisposable`, so those should be wrapped in `using`s as well.

Comment: That doesn't explain 1. What the KeySize property actually does? 2. Why no exception occurs?

Comment: How about [looking at the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rijndaelmanaged.cs,563e17e251686594)?

Comment: You can encrypt a packet of 10 bytes (The blocksize ?) with a keysize of 192 ?

Comment: As a side note, default KeySize is 256, while BlockSize is 128.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.key(v=vs.110).aspx) and [KeySize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.keysize(v=vs.110).aspx) properties of the RijndaelManaged class are inherited from the base [SymmetricAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) class. The precise behavior of these properties isn't well documented in MSDN Library, but if you look at the [SymmetricAlgorithm source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/symmetricalgorithm.cs,97c6f2476150a40d), you'll see that the Key and KeySize properties interact with each other as follows:

- When you set the Key property, the KeySize property is automatically set to the length of the new key in bits.
- When you set the KeySize property, the existing Key is cleared out (and a new random key is automatically generated the next time Key is accessed).

Therefore, if you're setting the Key property, there's no point in setting the KeySize property beforehand.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I expected, I will award the bounty when it's available for me to do so.